# How to adjust Combine's Publisher demand without a custom Subscriber?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

In [Combine](http://developer.apple.com/reference/combine) framework there's a concept of a [demand](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subscribers/demand), which allows signalling backpressure to [publishers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher).

Suppose I have a simple publisher:

```swift
let numbers = Publishers.Sequence<ClosedRange<Int>, Error>(sequence: 0...100)
```

I would like to download certain URLs that use these numbers as arguments. I also would like a next download to start only after a previous download has finished.

A naive approach then would look like this:

```swift
let subscription = numbers.sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }, receiveValue: {
  let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get?value=\($0)")!
  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { 
    $0.map { print(String(data: $0, encoding: .utf8)!) }
  }.resume()
})
```

Unfortunately, this wouldn't satisfy the requirement of waiting for a previous download to complete before starting the next one. As far as I know, `sink` function would return a value of type [`AnyCancellable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anycancellable), not of type [`Subscription`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subscription). If the latter was the case, we could call the [`request`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subscription/3213720-request) function on the `subscription` with a specific demand after an upload completes.

What would be the best way to control demand of a subscription provided by `sink` or any other standard Combine `Subscriber`?

Comment: Personally I feel it would be better to handle it in an operation (formerly called `NSOperation`) and you can add dependencies on ongoing operations of the same type. It would also encapsulate much of the code and could return a `Result` which could be handled by a `Future`

Comment: I understand that there are other ways to implement this, but my question is specifically about Combine and its API. It seems puzzling that support for backpressure is advertised as a distinguishing feature of Combine, but there's no easy solution for a common need that supposedly could be solved with backpressure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out, [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204712-flatmap) operator takes an additional `maxPublishers` argument that takes a [`Subscribers.Demand`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subscribers/demand) value. In combination with the [`Future`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/Future) publisher, this allows the `numbers` publisher to wait until the future is able to process a given value before sending a next one.

Applying this to the original code, downloading values one after another would look like this:

```swift
enum DownloadError: Error {
    case noData
}

let subscription = numbers.flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) { number in
    Future { promise in
        let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get?value=\(number)")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            switch ($0, $2) {
            case let (data?, nil):
                promise(.success(data))
            case let (nil, error?):
                promise(.failure(error))
            default:
                promise(.failure(DownloadError.noData))
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}.sink(
    receiveCompletion: { _ in print("errors should be handled here") },
    receiveValue: { print(String(data: $0, encoding: .utf8)!) }
)
```